# Android Emulator disconnects shortly after launching

Tags: android-emulator

when i launch an emulator or try to run an android project i get this error **-emulator: ../../src/xcb_io.c:249: process_responses: Assertion `(((long) (dpy->last_request_read) - (long) (dpy->request)) <= 0)' failed.** the emulator is visible for only a few seconds.the sdk and eclipse are correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem & after a lot of trying I found a solution...

this is very simple you need to give permission both emulator & ddms.

they are located in the /tools directory of android-sdk

first go to that directory, then run the following command :

```
$sudo chmod 755 emulator 
$sudo chmod 755 ddms
```

then :

```
$emulator -avd <name of avd>
```

Hope this will work

:)